# cannot retrieve data from table output

Tags: javascript

When I try to retrieve using my code below, I get `[object HTMLTableElement]`
I have no idea which part went wrong. I am trying to retrieve the directions as shown above and convert it into arrows instead of text direction keys. Thanks for any help.

Here is my code:

```js
function getManeuver() {
  var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id:ChIJ685WIFYViEgRHlHvBbiD5nE&destination=place_id:ChIJA01I-8YVhkgRGJb0fW4UX7Y&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('success', data);
      drawTable(data);

    }
  });

  function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
      drawRow(data.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i]);
    }
  }

  function drawRow(steps) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row);
    row.append($("<td>" + steps.maneuver + "</td>"));
  }
}

function getArrows() {
  var myTab = document.getElementById('personDataTable');
  document.getElementById("Arrows").innerHTML = myTab;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Get Code</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css">

</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="getManeuver()">Get Maneuver</button>
  <table id="personDataTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Maneuver</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button onclick="getArrows()">Get Arrows</button>
  <p id="Arrows"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

I have results as shown:

```
Maneuver
undefined
turn-left
turn-left
turn-left
turn-right
turn-right
```

Comment: what's wrong in your code ? what are you expecting ?

Comment: I want to get the maneuver data instead of [object HTMLTableElement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` function will return DOM element with the specified id.  That's why all you got there is [object HTMLTableElement].

Instead, what you should try to achieve is retrieving the text inside your `<td>` elements. Since you're using jquery, maybe you should try this instead.

```
function getArrows() {
    $('#personDataTable td').each(function(idx, element) { 
        var text = $(element).text();
        $('#Arrows').append(text + ', ');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are getting whole table in `document.getElementById("Arrows").innerHTML` that's why you are getting `[object HTMLTableElement]` you need to append the table till you reach the element you want to print on label like the below

```js
var myTab = document.getElementById('personDataTable');
    document.getElementById("Arrows").innerHTML = myTab;
    console.log(myTab);
    
    console.log(document.getElementById('personDataTable').children[0].children[0].children[0].innerText);//the output of this will be "Maneuver"
    
    console.log(document.getElementById('personDataTable').children[0].children[0].children.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="getManeuver()">Get Maneuver</button>

<table id="personDataTable">


    <tr>
        
  <th>Maneuver</th>
        
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="getArrows()">Get Arrows</button>
 <p id="Arrows"></p>
```